# Allow Users to edit ranges in excel sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a work book which has different sheets having names as user names(windows login) of different users. Now I have added a code to add new sheet to the workbook for a new user. 
I wanted to give permission to the same user to edit certain ranges through the code in the new sheet created. If I unlock certain cells all the users will be able to edit the ranges in this user's sheet. How I can get the 'allow users to edit ranges' functionality through vba

```
    Sub add_new_user()

newUser = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").newUserTextBox.Value

struserdn = GetUserFullName(newUser)

If struserdn <> "Error" Then

    answer = MsgBox("Do you want to add the following user?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & struserdn & vbNewLine & newUser & "@abcd.com", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New User")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Dim newUSheet As Worksheet
        Worksheets("Example_sheet").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Example_sheet")
        Set newUSheet = ActiveSheet
        newUSheet.Name = newUser
        newUSheet.Unprotect "123" 

        'need some code here to allow the newUser to edit ranges A4:F10000

        newUSheet.protect "123"
        newUSheet.Rows("A1").Value = struserdn

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "User name not found!", , "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You stated some intentions and showed some code but failed to ask a question. Do you have a question? If so, what is it?

Comment: I wanted to give permission to the user for particular range. In excel we can use 'allow users to edit ranges' option, in which i can give permission to particular user access to particular cells. I wanted same in VBA

Comment: how can i get allow users to edit ranges option in VBA? for particular user

Comment: A user is allowed to edit a sheet if the sheet is unprotected. So, if you want to implement that in VBA then you could use `Worksheets("Example_sheet").Unprotect "somepassword"`.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code loops through all sheets in the workbook and unlocks those sheets that has the same namne as the windows username.

edit:
Added som lines to the code.

```
Dim winUser As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

winUser = Environ("username")

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name = winUser Then

        ws.Unprotect     ' You can add a password here

    else

        ws.protect        ' You can add a password here

    End If

Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Range("A1:B1").Locked = False` you can mark a range as unlocked in protection mode.

If you now use something like

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

to protect the sheet, then the previous unlocked range can be edited by a user and any other range of the sheet can not.

---

If you mean that user A can only edit sheet A and user B can only edit sheet B, this is not possible in any secure way.

Comment: By this every user of the workbook will be able to edit the ranges. i wanted it only for the particular user

Comment: You can do this only without VBA I think. You can not specify a user for different ranges. But you can do this via the Ribbon/Menu only. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/289270/how-to-apply-different-passwords-or-permissions-to-separate-ranges-in-worksheets-in-excel